Javascript in inline tags running multiple times in Oqtane - Blazor - 2sxc
I'm using the Oqtane CMS/Framework (with Blazor) with 2sxc apps.
I added this 2sxc app (made just for this test) to a single page with this content:
<div id="something">Something</div>

<script>
    const thisVar = "abc";
    document.querySelector("#something").style.display = "block";
</script>

If I move away from this page I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')"
So the script is executing again (in pages where the module does not exist), but the html content does not exist.
If I move away from this page and then access it again, I get: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Identifier 'thisVar ' has already been declared".
Does the module retain the script execution after moving away from the page?
I know the optimal way to implement javascript in these apps is with external files, but I need to migrate the current working apps into Oqtane and then refactor them to better standards (there is a lot of dynamic razor code in these scripts).
Any good and simple guides or recommendations available on this subject?

"Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')" means that it's not finding the element #something; you could use optional chaining to only set the style if the element exists.

@mykaf the point is to not run the js outside the page it's on.

Is this script included on all pages? Can you remove it from the other pages?

It's just in one page.

Sorry, if it's just in one page, then what is "outside the page it's on"?

Other pages in the CMS.

It seems to be a bug in the way scripts are being added. Best open an issue.

BTW: I'm not sure if you are describing the problem correctly. Best mention what rendering mode etc. you're using - as this has a strong effect on the JS behavior. Then be sure to verify / report when exactly the problem happens, just to be sure that it's not being injected correctly in a scenario that you don't expect.

@iJungleBoy Already did. But Shawn claims it's an expected behaviour, so I thought it was issue with my implementation. https://github.com/oqtane/oqtane.framework/discussions/4888

So it appears that a) there was a bug in 2sxc where the script was added multiple times and b) you need to be aware of the script remaining in the browser memory. This is not a problem in your simple script, but if you had a timer or watcher, that would continue to run.  Next 2sxc release in a few days...
